# How to use .abs- (from abstract) from UI library LESS?

Tags: magento2.3, css, frontend, less, ui-library

Magento Documentation for UI Library has said to use "**Extend class names should have prefix .abs- (from abstract)**"

There is no other explanation for the usage in the [documentation](https://magento-devdocs.github.io/magento2-ui-library/index.html)

How should we use it in LESS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a naming convention so it's easier to know which classes are designed to be extended, they are to be used like this:

```
.your-selector {
    &:extend(.abs-reset-list all)
}
```

Where `.abs-reset-list` is the selector you want to extend.

This is core LESS functionality and isn't really related to Magento other than they prefix their class names with `abs-`